# How to test that a block is called within a thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I am working on wrapping the `ruby-mqtt` gem into a class which implements a `subscribe` and `publish` method. The `subscribe` method connects to the server and listens in a separate thread because this call is synchronous.

```
module PubSub
class MQTT
    attr_accessor :host, :port, :username, :password

    def initialize(params = {})
        params.each do |attr, value|
            self.public_send("#{attr}=", value)
        end if params
        super()
    end

    def connection_options
        {
            remote_host: self.host,
            remote_port: self.port,
            username: self.username,
            password: self.password,
        }
    end

    def subscribe(name, &block)
        channel = name
        connect_opts = connection_options
        code_block = block
        ::Thread.new do
            ::MQTT::Client.connect(connect_opts) do |c|
                c.get(channel) do |topic, message|
                    puts "channel: #{topic} data: #{message.inspect}"
                    code_block.call topic, message
                end
            end
        end
    end

    def publish(channel = nil, data)
        ::MQTT::Client.connect(connection_options) do |c|
            c.publish(channel, data)
        end
    end     

end
end
```

I have a test that I have written using rspec to test the class but it does not pass.

```
mqtt = ::PubSub::MQTT.new({host: "localhost",port: 1883})
block = lambda { |channel, data|  puts "channel: #{channel} data: #{data.inspect}"}
block.should_receive(:call).with("channel", {"some" => "data"})
thr = mqtt.subscribe("channel", &block)
mqtt.publish("channel", {"some" => "data"})
```

When I run the following [ruby-mqtt-example](https://github.com/CloudMQTT/ruby-mqtt-example/blob/master/app.rb) I have now problems at all.

```
uri = URI.parse ENV['CLOUDMQTT_URL'] || 'mqtt://localhost:1883'
conn_opts = {
  remote_host: uri.host,
  remote_port: uri.port,
  username: uri.user,
  password: uri.password,
}

# Subscribe example
Thread.new do
  puts conn_opts
  MQTT::Client.connect(conn_opts) do |c|
    # The block will be called when you messages arrive to the topic
    c.get('test') do |topic, message|
      puts "#{topic}: #{message}"
    end
  end
end

# Publish example
puts conn_opts
MQTT::Client.connect(conn_opts) do |c|
  # publish a message to the topic 'test'
  loop do
    c.publish('test', 'Hello World')
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong when I simply create a class and separate out the publish and subscribe logic? My guess is that it has something to do with Threading in the function call but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE

I believe I know why the test is not passing and it is because when I pass a `lambda` in to `subscribe` expecting it to receive a call it actually will not receive the call when it exits the method or until `publish` is called. So I would like to rephrase the question to: How do I test that a block is called within a thread? If someone answers, "you don't", then the question is: How do you test that block is being called in an infinite loop like in the example of calling `get` within `ruby-mqtt` gem.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you doing a `sleep` at the end of your rspec test snippet?  It could be that the test case is exiting before the other thread has a chance to invoke `call` on the block.

Comment: I tried a sleep of two seconds but I will try a longer sleep. I am not getting any error. The test just doesn't pass.

Comment: Thanks for your help @north636. A longer `sleep` in getting `"channel: channel data: {"some" => "data"}"` logged to the console which shows that the block within `get` it is being called but my test does not pass. I revised my question to ask how do I test this code.

Comment: Where did you put your `sleep`? It needs to go at the end of the RSpec block as @north636 said and as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RSpec expectations machinery will work fine with threads, as evidenced by the following example, which passes:

```
def foo(&block)
  block.call(42)
end

describe "" do
  it "" do
    l = lambda {}
    expect(l).to receive(:call).with(42)
    Thread.new { foo(&l) }.join
  end
end
```

The `join` waits for the thread(s) to finish before going further.

Comment: I had the sleep in the same place as your example. The difference between your example and the my test is I am also checking that it has a parameter in the call as well ie. `block.should_receive(:call).with({"some" => "data"})` I will except your answer because it did get my test to pass which is sufficient. But I am wondering why asserting that the block should receive certain parameters caused the test to fail.

Comment: I've updated the example to include the use of `with`. It would help if you could share the specific error you're getting.